# How do you clear image cache in iPhone 5S Safari browser?

Tags: iphone, image, caching, browser, safari

Please forgive me if this question sounds like clearing Safari cache/cookies in General->Settings.

The issue is as follows:

We have a custom webpage where user can upload his profile icon/image by choosing from Phone's photo library or taking a photo.
The 1st time user uploads an image P1,  it's uploaded successfully to server.
If user refreshes the webpage and tries to upload a different image  P2,  P1 is uploaded to server.

Problem persists even after clearing browser cache. 
If I kill browser and clear cache,  then I'll be able to upload a new image.

This problem does not occur on browsers on Google devices or on PC.

Somehow iPhone browser remembers the image object and I need to find a way to clear it.

Answer (score 40):

1. Launch the **Settings app** from the Home screen of your iPhone or iPad.
2. Scroll down and tap on **Safari**.
3. Now scroll all the way to the bottom and tap on **Advanced**.
4. Tap on **Website Data**. Notice here you can see how much space on your iPhone or iPad website data is taking up.
5. Scroll to the bottom again and tap on **Remove All Website Data**.
6. Confirm one more time you'd like to delete all data.

Comment: This also seems to clear javascript files etc. from memory. I was having error problems with a javascript app which didn't respond to changes in the files, but when I checked on an iPad it was ok. Clearing the cache from the phone fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Launch the **Settings** app from the Home screen of your iPhone or iPad.
Scroll down and tap on **Safari**.
Now scroll all the way to the bottom and tap on **Advanced**.
Tap on **Website Data.** Notice here you can see how much space on your iPhone or iPad website data is taking up.
Scroll to the bottom again and tap on **Remove All Website Data.**
**Confirm one more time you'd like to delete all data.**